# Proving composition of exterior product homomorphisms is 0-map

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exterior-algebra

I am trying to prove that if $$d_r (e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} \wedge ... \wedge e_{i_r}) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^r (-1)^{j-1}a_{i_j}(e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} ... \wedge e_{i_(j-1)} \wedge e_{i_(j+1)} \wedge ... \wedge e_{i_r}),$$ then $d_{r-1} \circ d_r = 0$

I worked it out the point where I have $$2 *\sum\limits_{j=1}^r \sum\limits_{k < j} (-1)^{j+k} a_{i_j}a_{i_k} (e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} ... \wedge e_{i_(j-1)} \wedge e_{i_(j+1)} \wedge ... e_{i_{k-1}} \wedge e_{i_{k+1}} \wedge ... \wedge e_{i_r})$$ since there is some symmetry in the way we took the sum. However, I am not sure how I can simplify this to $0$. I know a wedge product is $0$ if there are two terms that are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an off by one error.  If you think about it the only way this could possibly work is if $$a_{i_j}a_{i_k}\bigwedge_{l=1,l\neq j,k}^r e_{i_l}$$ occurred both positively and negatively.

You should be able to convince yourself that the sum you want is $$\sum_{j = 1}^r\sum_{k=1,j\neq k}^r \varepsilon_{j,k} a_{i_j} a_{i_k}\bigwedge_{l=1,l\neq j,k}^r e_{i_l}$$
where $\varepsilon_{j,k}$ is the sign (i.e. $\varepsilon_{j,k} = \pm 1$).  You can then show that $\varepsilon_{j,k}=-\varepsilon_{k,j}$.  By symmetry, we can consider just the $j<k$ case, in which case $\varepsilon_{j,k}$ corresponds to $j-1$ followed by $k-\mathbf{2}$ alternations giving $\varepsilon_{j,k}=(-1)^{(j-1)+(k-2)} = (-1)^{j+k-1}$ while $\varepsilon_{k,j}$ corresponds to $k-1$ alternations followed by $j-1$ alternations giving $\varepsilon_{k,j} = (-1)^{(j-1)+(k-1)}=(-1)^{j+k}$.  This should be enough to spell this out into a complete proof.

Comment: I understand everything except one small part: what is the purpose of the alternations? Is that to bring $e_{i_j}, e_{i_k}$ to the front of the wedge products?

Comment: @YunusSyed Yes, for the purpose of standardizing the wedge products.  Essentially $\varepsilon_{j,k}$ is the sign of $e_{i_j}\wedge e_{i_k} \wedge \bigwedge_{l=1,l\neq j,k}^r e_{i_l}$ relative to $\bigwedge_{l = 1}^r e_{i_l}$. One compact way to establish the result in the context of geometric algebra is $d(K) = a\cdot K$ where $a = \sum_{j=1}^r a_{i_j} e_{i_j}$ and $\cdot$ is an inner product. You then have $(d\circ d)(K) = a\cdot(a\cdot K) = (a\wedge a)\cdot K = 0$. $a\cdot(b\wedge K)=(a\cdot b)K-b\wedge(a\cdot K)$ motivates pulling to the front, i.e. counting how deep $a\cdot$ goes.

Comment: I don't understand why we need to use the sign.

Comment: @YunusSyed It comes from the same $(-1)^{(j-1)}$ you have in your original formula. The difference comes when you apply $d_{r-1}$ to the $j$th subterm of $d_{r}(\bigwedge_{l=1}^r e_{i_l})$. You'll get a sum with a $(-1)^{(m-1)}$ factor just as before, where $m$ is the index of summation, but for the terms corresponding to $e_{i_k}$, $m = k$ if $k<j$ and $m=k-1$ if $k>j$ since there will be a missing $e_{i_j}$ in the latter case so the index will be off by one.

Comment: Hmm...so the terms cancel because of this? I understood how the -1 powers come to the front but how can we just cancel terms in the sum?

Comment: In your double summation, you "folded" over the $j=k$ diagonal to get the triangular sum with the inner sum over $k<j$.  You (incorrectly) got a factor of $2$ by adding together the symmetric terms, i.e. the corresponding terms where $k>j$. If you understood my previous comment, you should see that these symmetric terms have *opposite* signs, however, so they should have cancelled out.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for answering all my questions. I guessed it had to be something k,j = - j,k so when I got the factor of 2 I figured i made a mistake somewhere. Thanks again for everything.